# App Bundle build failure: reserved file or directory error

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-build

I can't build my AAB because both in Unity and in Android Studio (when exporting the project) it fails with this error:

> file 'root/res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png' uses reserved file or directory name 'res'.

I searched up a lot and I can't find a valid solution to this issue, and I can't think of a way to avoid it since the files it refers to are added at the moment of building. Can anybody help me with this? Thanks a lot.